Не получается передать данные между React приложением и php
Я передаю данные между react приложением на сервер и возвращаю их обратно, выводом в консоль. Использую для получения переданных данных в php переменную среды $_POST.
Код в React приложении:
fetch('http://localhost/crypto.com/index.php', {
  method: 'POST', 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ name: 'Uber' })
})
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(resp => console.log(resp));

Код в php:
<?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    echo json_encode($_POST);
?>

Вывод в консоли реакт приложения

Как можно исправить баг?

Вместо фотки вставь сам текст ошибки... И сама ошибка не связана с теми кусками кода, что ты привел. Ты в "списочных" элементах не указал key...

Ну вы же обманываете нас)) Вы выводите это не в консоль, а в шаблон реакта и вам вполне себе говорят что должно быть. Причём напрямую, без завуилрований.

Ошибки нет, есть неверный вывод, а точнее вывод, который не соответствует тому, который должен быть. Вывод - {} (то есть пустой объект)

Замени .then(resp => JSON.stringify(resp)) на .then(resp => resp.json())

@ksa, VM168:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. Внёс правки, вот ошибка

Тогда напиши .then(resp => resp.text()) - хоть посмотришь что там тебе присылают...

@ksa,  присылают пустую строку

В вопросе ввел изменения, такой вывод в первый раз вижу, с ним что-то сделать можно ?

Проблема была в пеправильном формате данных в параметре body.
fetch('http://localhost/crypto.com/index.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: 'name=Uber' // Corrected body format
})
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(resp => console.log(resp))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

body принимает строкуи если мы используем метод
JSON.stringify({name: 'Uber'})
то ожидаемо получим строку

Но, если мы передадим правильный формат в body, то php код:
<?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    echo json_encode($_POST['name']);
?>

отработает корректно и выведет:

Объяснил криво косо, но надеюсь понятно.
